# Anyone know how to actually USE the 'built-in' SVG Icons [in SyrveyJs]?

Tags: angular, angular-material, surveyjs

I've Googled, I've tried to read their docs (which are kinda thin imo. I can't find any actual "reference" docs anywhere), etc., and no joy.

I'm just trying to add a `icon-checkbox` into an html element in my survey json model.. with some text after it. e.g. `[√] Thanks for completing this questionnaire!`

I was trying to use an Angular Material icon, but if SurveyJs has some built-in, all the better. But again, I can't find any actual usage examples.

TIA! :D

Answer (score 1):

The question duplicates the following GitHub issue: https://github.com/surveyjs/survey-library/issues/6456.

Solution:
To use built-in icons, include them to HTML content as follows: `<svg><use href="#icon-name"></use></svg>`.

```
<svg><use href="#icon-v2check_24x24"></use></svg>
```

For instance, the following code references the [V2Check_24x24](https://github.com/surveyjs/survey-library/blob/0be44aef43c62f5790bd0c7d56e63b57aa780687/src/images/V2Check_24x24.svg) icon in a `completedHtml` property:

```
export const json = {
  completedHtml:
    '<svg><use href="#icon-v2check_24x24"></use></svg><p><h4>Thank you!&nbsp;&nbsp;Your response has been submitted.&nbsp;&nbsp;Please allow 20 business days for screening.&nbsp;<br />You will receive an email once your application has been processed.</h4></p>',
  elements: [
    ...
  ]
};
```

[image]

Built-in cons are available as a part of the currently applied theme. For instance, icons available with the Default V2 theme are placed in the following folder: https://github.com/surveyjs/survey-library/tree/0be44aef43c62f5790bd0c7d56e63b57aa780687/src/images.

You can also review how icons are referenced in [defaultV2Css.ts](https://github.com/surveyjs/survey-library/blob/0be44aef43c62f5790bd0c7d56e63b57aa780687/src/defaultCss/defaultV2Css.ts#L538).

You can also use custom icons.
To register a custom SVG icon and use it in a survey, use the `SvgRegistry.registerIconFromSvg` method. For instance, the following code registers a custom SVG icon with the `icon-test` id.

```
import { SvgRegistry } from "survey-core";

var svg =
  '<svg viewBox="0 0 12 12" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M11.35 1.34999L10.65 0.649994L6.05002 5.24999L1.35002 0.649994L0.650024 1.34999L5.25002 6.04999L0.650024 10.65L1.35002 11.35L6.05002 6.74999L10.65 11.35L11.35 10.65L6.75002 6.04999L11.35 1.34999Z"/></svg>';

SvgRegistry.registerIconFromSvg("icon-test", svg);
```

[View Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-wind-9g87qf?file=/src/SurveyComponent.jsx)

Answer (score 0):

actually in docs ,seems them only offer to replace a icon to other like:

```
Survey.settings.customIcons["icon-import"] = "icon-export";
Survey.settings.customIcons["icon-export"] = "icon-import";

// In modular applications:
import { settings } from "survey-core";
settings.customIcons["icon-import"] = "icon-export";
settings.customIcons["icon-export"] = "icon-import";
```